# Using dynamic type in LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm using LINQ for querying the database. I'm using dynamic keyword in queries. I don't know this dynamic mechanism in depth, so I don't understand what's going on.
The situation follows. The following section of code:

```
var qGroup = qLocalOrd.GroupBy("new(...)", "it");
var qGroupCast = (qGroup as IQueryable<IGrouping<dynamic,dynamic>>).AsEnumerable();

var qAgg = from ordg in qGroupCast
select new {
ordg.Key,
Agg = (ordg.Key.OsID + " " + ordg.Key.NameOs + "\n" + 
(ordg as IEnumerable<dynamic>).Aggregate("Составные части:\n", ...).Trim('\n') + ...)
};
```

Works just fine. But when I'm adding this to the end:

```
var qPlain = qAgg.Cast<dynamic>().AsQueryable().Select("new(Key.SubSchet, Key.NameSubSchet, ...)");
qPlain.Dump();
```

I'm receiving an error like "No field "Key" exists in type "Object"". It's the same if I use

```
(qAgg as IEnumerable<dynamic>)
```

So at this point dynamic treatment of qAgg elements is broken somewhy.

Why does this happen and how to make this thing work?

Comment: I don't see any reasonable reason for using dynamic with Linq.

Comment: With that attitude , Good luck !

Comment: What overload of `Select` is used on the return of `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Well, there's only one overload of Select in Dynamic Expression API (from VisualStudio examples): public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source,
    string selector, params object[] values);